# wired internet upload speed is slow compared to windows

Tags: networking, upload

Using http://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/UploadLargeFile:

Linux upload of 1.6mB file had a speed of 8kBs

Windows upload of a 1.4mB file had a speed of 450kBs

nic card SIS 900

I really like Ubuntu but this could mean switching back to my no longer supported Windows xp in order to run a web server. I have tried a few things found here on Ubuntu but nothing has worked. That said from the look of one of the other speed testers I have used it looks like the upload starts out really fast then *very* quickly gets extremely slow. I try that same test in windows and the speed stays fast. If you want to see the test I am talking about google for "test upload speed" and click the button that says "run speed test"!

Is there a setting in Ubuntu that slows a connection but only when the data transfer rate is above a limit?

**EDIT: I rebooted and selected an older Linux kernel using grub and now my upload using azurespeed.com is 474kBs!**

- 4.4.0-42-generic = very slow upload speed
- 4.4.0-38-generic = very slow upload speed
- 4.4.0-34-generic = very slow upload speed
- 3.13.0-88-generic = fast upload speed

`sudo lshw -C net` with 3.13.0-88:

```
   *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 90
   serial: 00:13:d4:73:2c:66
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis900 driverversion=v1.08.10 Apr. 2 2006 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.100 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=11 mingnt=52 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:a800(size=256) memory:ed103000-ed103fff memory:40000000-4001ffff**
```

`sudo lshw -C net` with 4.4.0-42-generic (identical to the above):

```
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 90
   serial: 00:13:d4:73:2c:66
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis900 driverversion=v1.08.10 Apr. 2 2006 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.100 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=11 mingnt=52 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:a800(size=256) memory:ed103000-ed103fff memory:40000000-4001ffff
```

I will add the output for the other Linux kernel ASAP

Comment: Why Azure? Is the problem also present in other applications?

Comment: I have tried a few speed testers and all but http://www.speedtest.net/ show this same problem.

Comment: If it depends on kernel version, please mention the exact versions you tried.

Comment: @Smertrios2007: If at least one connection allows fast transmission speed this is most likely caused by something else than kernel changes. The changes probably just uncover a different issue. I'd be interested to know whether this affects connections over the local network where internet speed is irrelevant.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output, in terminal, of `sudo lshw -C net`. Let me know when it's available for me to look at. Cheers, Al

Comment: Are you using DSL? Cable modem? Something else? Cheers, Al

Comment: It could very well be a kernel bug in 4.4; I would report that.

Comment: I updated the post with the output of 'lshw -C net' when using both linux kernels.

Comment: internet is cable internet

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, so thanks for posting your solution, I am using v3.18.140 kernel now, and the upload speed is high.
Actually, the reason of the low upload speed is a driver incompatibility. Due to an update during v3.19 kernel development, the sis900 NIC driver is partly incompatible with v3.19 and higher kernel versions.